# VueRouter keeps component active after navigation

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following router defined:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "home",
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: "/hello",
            name: "hello",
            component: Hello
        },
        {
            path: "/foobar/:slug",
            name: "foobar",
            component: require("./views/Foobar.vue").default
        }
    ]
});
```

This is working and everything is correctly navigated in the `<router-view></router-view>`.

When I navigate to the "foobar" router; I made something that starts the Webcam.
But when I navigate to a different route, the webcam stays active..

This is how I navigate:

```
<router-link replace :to="{ name: 'home' }">home</router-link>
```

And

```
this.$router.replace({name: "workshop"});
```

How can I force a hard navigation or something like that? I want the previous component(s) to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the webcam first

Possible solution:
Within the Vue route component where you use the webcam, create a `destroy() {}` function and stop the webcam there. It will turn it off before exiting the route.

Comment: But what can I do to close EVERY component after navigation to another? i do not any component to stay alive at the background..

Comment: it automatically does, the webcam just doesn't get turned off

Comment: This is not really the issue. I get what you mean, but that's not what I'm looking for.
When i navigate to a different component, that previous component/view should clear itself. now it looks like that it's stil active, but i want to re-render the component when i navigate back to the foobar-route.

Comment: Niek is right. Vue router always destroys component when you navigate away unless `keep-alive` component is used. Webcam is browser API and it doesn's switch off just because some JavaScript (vue) component is destroyed. You need to turn it off yourself in `destroy` hook...